# Run 'docker volume create' with Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a Rails app I am deploying in Docker containers via Ansible. My app includes three containers so far:

- A Docker volume container (created with `docker volume create --name dbdata`)
- A Postgres container (with `volumes_from` dbdata)
- The Rails app container (which links to the postgres container)

My deploy playbook is working, but I had to run the `docker volume create` command on the server via SSH. I'd love to do that via Ansible, so I could deploy a fresh instance of the app onto an empty container.

Is there a way to run `docker volume create` via Ansible, or is there some other way to do it? I checked the docs for the Ansible Docker module but it doesn't look like they support `volume create` yet. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Ansible can run arbitrary commands using the `command` or `shell` modules, so anything you can run on the command line you can probably run via ansible.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but didn't know how to do `state=present` like the Docker module does for containers. Though if you run `docker volume create` twice with the same name, the second one won't do anything because the volume will already exist. Hmmm!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one option, using the `command` module.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: check if myvolume exists
      command: docker volume inspect myvolume
      register: myvolume_exists
      failed_when: false

    - name: create myvolume
      command: docker volume create --name myvolume
      when: myvolume_exists|failed
```

We first check if the volume exists by using `docker volume inspect`.  We save the result of that task in the variable `myvolume_exists`, and then we only *create* the volume if the `inspect` task failed.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use `-v` argument to create named volumes, from man page of docker run:

> If you supply a name, Docker creates a named volume by that name.

```
  - name: Run mariadb
    docker_container:
      name: mariadb-container
      image: mariadb
      env:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "secret-password"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
        MYSQL_USER: "user"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

`mariadb-data` is a named volume which was automatically created by docker:

```
$ docker volume inspect mariadb-data
[
    {
        "Name": "mariadb-data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mariadb-data/_data",
        "Labels": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can manage docker volumes with Ansible's own [docker_volume](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_volume_module.html) module. New in version 2.4.

Examples:

```
- name: Create a volume
  docker_volume:
    name: volume_one

- name: Remove a volume
  docker_volume:
    name: volume_one
    state: absent

- name: Create a volume with options
  docker_volume:
    name: volume_two
    driver_options:
      type: btrfs
      device: /dev/sda2
```